# Is there a way to make bundled/grouped Android notifications expand on tap, rather than launching an activity in the app?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I intend to interact with Android notifications simply through the on tap events of each, rather than having an activity listing them out inside the app, this is why I'm asking if there is a way to just expand the grouped notifications on tap (not just on the arrow) so that they can be tapped individually. This would mirror the behavior of other mobile platforms and would be nice and fast to have.

This is for Android phones with no real api limits, I'll do what I can to find a workaround if the solution is for a higher api level.